# Reflection reverses a root string

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, reflection, root-systems

I am trying to understand the part of the proof In Fulton's and Harris's *Represantation Theory* book where he shows that the length of the root is at most 4:

**Theorem** If $\alpha,\beta$ are roots with $\beta \neq \pm \alpha$, then the $\alpha$ string through $\beta$, i.e. the roots of the form 
\begin{equation*}
\beta - p\alpha, \beta -(p-1)\alpha, \dots, \beta - \alpha, \beta, \beta + \alpha, \beta + 2\alpha, \dots, \beta + q\alpha 
\end{equation*}
has at most four in a string, i.e. $p+q \leq 3$; in addition, $p-q=n_{\beta\alpha}$

where $n_{\beta \alpha}= 2\frac{(\beta,\alpha)}{(\alpha,\alpha)}$ (positive definite form on a vector space $V$) and then the reflection of a root $\beta$ in the hyperplane orthogonal to a root $\alpha$ is given by 
\begin{equation*}
W_{\alpha}(\beta) = \beta - n_{\beta \alpha}\alpha
\end{equation*}

The part of the proof I don't understand is when he writes that
\begin{equation} 
W_{\alpha}(\beta + q\alpha) = \beta - p\alpha \quad (1)
\end{equation}
 , meaning that the reflection (in the hyperplane orthogonal to $\alpha$) reverses a root string. I read somewhere else  that this is geometrically an obvious fact but I can't see how. I get that by reflecting through $\alpha$ we just add a positive or negative multiple of $\alpha$ to any root but I really cannot see why $(1)$  is true.

Comment: It's hard to say because it depends on what is already proven at that step. Maybe add that.

Comment: Sure, I'll add that soon.

Comment: @Torsten, it appears that they only use the axioms of  a crystallographic root system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It follows from the definition of $W_\alpha$ that for $k \in \mathbb Z$, $W_\alpha(\beta+k\alpha)$ is of the form $\beta + \ell(k) \alpha$ for some $\ell(k) \in \mathbb Z$. Consequently, that root string is invariant under $W_\alpha$. Further, because $W_\alpha(\alpha) = -\alpha$ and $W_\alpha$ is linear, we have

$$k_1 > k_2 \Rightarrow \ell(k_2) > \ell(k_1),$$

i.e. $\ell$ reverses the order of the root chain. That's enough to prove the statement $W_\alpha(\beta +q\alpha) =\beta-p\alpha$, since these are the two "end points" of the chain.

Comment: That is really nice! Thanks @Torsten !

Answer (score 1):

Since the only roots involved in this theorem are $\alpha$ and $\beta$, you may assume that you are in a rank 2 root system (of type $A_1\times A_1$, $A_2$, $B_2$ or $G_2$). There are only finitely many cases and they can all be easily checked.

Comment: You're using the result which we want to prove first, that is: $p-q=n_{\beta \alpha}$. To prove the  theorem on the length of a string they first prove what you taken to be true and then, using this, prove the theorem on the length of a string. So the bit which I don't understand is used to show that the result you assumed to be true  is actually true. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: I see. I misread the question.

Comment: Thanks! I hope you don't mind me asking but why is it enough to show that it holds for (distinct) root systems of rank 2?

Comment: Because the two dimensional plane containing $\alpha$ and $\beta$ contains a rank 2 root system that is invariant under the action of $W_\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks @David !